Displaying article title in fancyhdr header with conditionals
I use the tip found here How to display article title in fancyhdr header to display article title in fancy header. But I'm not able to make it works within a condition sequence.
As an example, this works :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{A title of something}

\makeatletter
\edef\mytitle{\@title}
\makeatother
\chead{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    Test text.
\end{document}

But that doesn't :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{A title of something}

\newbool{beam}
\setbool{beam}{false}

\ifbool{beam}
    {   
    }   
    {
        \makeatletter
        \edef\mytitle{\@title}
        \makeatother
        \chead{\mytitle}
    }
 
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    Test text.
\end{document}

Here are the errors:
ligne 25: You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode. \end{document}
ligne 25: Missing $ inserted. \end{document}
ligne 25: Missing $ inserted. \end{document}    


Your MWE compiles fine for me, using pdflatex and lualatex. Only a warning of no author given is issued.

\makeatletter does nothing when used in the argument to another command. To be precise, with your code \@title has already been tokenized as
\@•t•i•t•l•e

(six tokens, the bullets are used just to separate them) before \makeatletter does its work.
You should change the way you define \mytitle. The problem to solve is that \maketitle will redefine \@title to empty, so we can define \mytitle just before executing \maketitle.
This way, whether you set \title before or after the related code with \ifbool will be irrelevant.
Note that \let\mytitle\@title is much more efficient than \protected@edef (not \edef, because this can break several valid LaTeX constructs).
Beware of unprotected endlines!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/before}{\let\mytitle\@title}
\makeatother

\newbool{beam}
\setbool{beam}{false}

\ifbool{beam}{%
  % perhaps something here
}{%
  \chead{\mytitle}%
}
 
\title{A title of something}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

Test text.

\end{document}


